# Python - Parsing using xml.etree.ElementTree failes due to an ampersand('&') in XML files

Tags: python, xml

Due to '&' in XML files, parsing XML files fails.
The code is simple as shown below.

```
xmlparse = Xet.parse(input_file_path + file_name, parser=Xet.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
```

I found '&' in the XML files causing the below error.

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1839, column 1016

and I can find the '&' character in the indicated line and column.

what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely makes XML files not well-formed.

There are two ways to handle it:

- Use CData section.
- Entitized ampersand character.

The 2nd method is easier and requires replacement of `&` with its entity `&amp;`

For example, `<city>dog & pony</city>` should become `<city>dog &amp; pony</city>`